# Help transforming a basic equation

Tags: analysis

Although this seems to be super basic, I cannot get my head around which steps I have to perform to transform $x^{2^{n+1}}\cdot x^{2^{n+1}}$ into $x^{2^{n+2}}$.

When I rewrite it as $x^{2^{{n+1}^2}}$ and the there are not braces, the power binds the strongest, that would lead to $x^{2^{n^2+2n+1}}$.

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions.

Comment: $a^x\cdot a^y = a^{x+y}$, not $a^{xy}.$

Comment: God I'm stupid. Thank you so much!

Comment: Not stupid -- just not quite used to these rules yet. Same as the rest of us when we first learned them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a basic fact that I'm assuming that you know:
$$
x^a \cdot x^b = x^ {a+b}.
$$
In your case, $a$ and $b$ are the same, and both are $2^{n+1}$. So all you need to know is what is
$$
a + b = 2^{n+1} + 2^{n+1}?
$$
Well, it's two copies of $2^{n+1}$, so it's
$$
2^1\cdot 2^{n+1} = 2^{n+2}
$$
by the same $a$-and-$b$ fact above. And that makes 
the final answer be
$$
2^{2^{n+2}}.
$$